# Pass multiple parameters with OData URL

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I want to pass multiple parameters in my Get Request using OData Protocol. Below is what I am doing.

I am using fiddler for GET request which is as follows

```
https://127.0.0.1/odata/controllerName('param1','param2')
```

In my controller class, I have two controller methods. First controller methods accepts only one parameter and second accepts two parameters. Controller method with one parameter works fine.When I am requesting controller method with two parameters, It invokes controller method with one parameter. I am not able to understand why it does not recognize controller method with two parameters. Or OData does not support multiple parameters.

Controller method 1

```
public int controllerName([FromOdataUri] string key);
```

Controller Method 2

```
public int controllerName([FromODataUri] string param1, [FromODataUri] string param2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the OData protocol, if the key of entity composites of 2 properties, then you can  query it in this way:

```
    ~/odata/EntitySet(key1='key1',key2='key2')
```

But if you don't have such key, then you may need Functions, which are called with GET, and the parameters are passed in in URL, such as

```
    ~/odata/Products(33)/Default.CalculateGeneralSalesTax(state='WA') 
    ~/odata/GetSalesTaxRate(state='CA')
```

please refer this sample: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataFunctionSample/

you can add as much parameters as you want.

Comment: Due the link samples... seem there were a need for implementation of Composite Key Handler, if you want to call it like that...

Answer (score 2):

OData takes one parameter, but it can be a JSON dictionary passed as the request body. [See the example here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-actions) under the heading "Invoking the Action" and Google around for **ODataActionParameters** to see how .NET's WebAPI implements the OData parameter dictionary requirement.